# Ninject.Mvc5 does not work with mono

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

Am following video tutorial from [you-tube](http://www.f6build.com/complete-web-application-step-by-step-using-asp-net-mvc-5-ef-ninject-linq-sql-server-twitter-bootstrap-moq-part3/) for making web app with ASP.Net. The guy teaching there is using Windows and Visual Studio. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and Monodevelop. Everything is set and running but Ninject (3.2.0.0) does not work.

After installing from NuGet, it created file `NinjectWebCommon.cs` have class `NinjectWebCommon`. below is my `RegisterServices` method which (according to tutor) is supposed to inject my list into controllers. I have tested and the method get called for sure but when I try to access my /Product/List I get error:

```
Application Exception
System.MissingMethodException
Default constructor not found for type OnlineShopping.WebUI.Controllers.ProductController

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x000a9] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory+DefaultControllerActivator.Create (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType) [0x00015] in <filename unknown>:0 
Version Information: 4.0.1 (tarball Tue May 12 15:39:23 UTC 2015); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

It seems the injection does not take place at all and I don't know why. I'm completely new to ASP and World of .Net so I might be missing something basic.
Here is the `RegisterServices` method:

```
  private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    { 
        Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository> ();
        mock.Setup (m => m.Products).Returns (new List<Product> {
            new Product{Name="Kilimanjaro Water", Price=1500},
            new Product{Name="Azam Cake", Price=200},
            new Product{Name="Huawei Y530", Price=195000},
        });
        kernel.Bind<IProductRepository> ().ToConstant(mock.Object);
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using OnlineShopping.Domain.Abstract;

namespace OnlineShopping.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProductRepository repository; 

        public ProductController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View (repository.Products);
        }
    }
}
```

The IProductRepository code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OnlineShopping.Domain.Entities;

namespace OnlineShopping.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> Products{ get; }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I have tried all solution I could find on google (hence SO) but I failed. Many did not represent what I experience (though basic error was the same) and others were in old version of Ninject and did not apply to my version.

Comment: Are you calling `RegisterServices` in global.asax?

Comment: reading ninject 3.x docs it says its not necessary and I can see it call the method, just not injecting the thing. Is that necessary?

Comment: Sorry my bad, you don't need to call that explicitly. I created a sample MVC app and installed `NInject` nuget and gave it a try, it is working fine for me using `Moq` to mock data. Can you show your `IProductRepository` code?

Comment: you did it on Linux with Mono? Its supposed to work in Windows not in Linux. I'm updating with IProductRepository code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Neither my code nor ninject is the culprit. Mono (4.0.1) have hidden bug that causes troubles somehow with Ninject.

I updated to mono 4.3 using weekly build documented [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/weekly-packages/) and all is well again.

Answer (score 1):

Ninject.Web.Common is a dependency of Ninject.MVC5, and it's a nice little utility to get your DI working quickly without modifying your source too much.

Unfortunately, this relies on a small "trick" of ASP.NET to pre-load the assembly and execute it's startup code during assembly binding, but I don't think this works correctly in Mono.

There is another project called Ninject.Mono.Web.Common Ninject.Mono which I believe is intended to be a workaround for this.  However, this is a much older version 3.0.x from 2012, and I wouldn't recommend using it.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Mono.Web.Common/

You can avoid this by not using Ninject.Web.Common and instead configuring ninject manually in your startup.

EDIT:

Looks like you need at least version 2.0.4 of WebActivatorEx to work with Mono, as previous versions did not.  Make sure you update your nuget packages to the latest versions.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/

Comment: checking I have WebActivatorEx 2.0.6 installed. So I guess I might be doing something incorrectly may be?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo - Well, somehow your NinjectDepencyResolver is not getting registered with MVC.  You don't have a custom Controller Factory do you?

Comment: No  don't have. All I did is following tutorial above as it is. Modified nothing at all. Where do I check for that resolver?

Comment: You can always use the "manual" approach documented in the first approach on the wiki https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

Comment: can you give me hints how? I see alot of stuffs for Ninject.mvc3. Also I searched in project and nowhere linking the Ninject DI class appears to be done

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo - I just gave you the hint.. go to the page I linked to above, and it tells you how to configure it manually in the first approach (there are two approaches listed there).  Ninject.MVC3 and MVC5 are essentially the same, they only have different nuget packages for some web.config differences.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that they are essentially the same. I will test both approach and come back with result

Comment: Both methods does present indeed same error. It seems to be something to do with ninject that is flawed somehow in mono. But strange that no one else have it reported

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Ninject?  Earlier you mentioned only 3.2.0, that's not the latest version.

Comment: updated to 3.2.2.0 still same error. Am really confused. Is there anything that works like Ninject that will not confuse me as I follow tutorial?

Comment: There are plenty of DI Containers... you might find StructureMap or SimpleInjector to be relatively easy.  My guess is that you're doing something wrong with Ninject, but I can't see your code so I don't know...  Try the sample application:  https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/tree/master/mvc3/src/SampleApplication

Comment: I will check them out (though I want to fix ninject thing). As to doing something wrong, I don't think so. Even If I just install ninject and run it, it fails. Removing ninject's file in app_start makes things work again.
See details https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/issues/41

Comment: turned out that stable mono (4.0.1) have hidden bug. I updated to 4.3 and everything is working now. Thanks for your posts. They have enlightened me alot on Ninject/Mono.